# Amazon S3 - is there any penalty for transitioning from Standard to Standard-IA?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am aware that Standard per month charge is more than Standard-IA.

I wasn't able to see in the docs if I upload to Standard and then set a Lifecycle rule to transition to Standard-IA is there a cost involved (for example to copy from Standard > Standard-IA) or is that part free?

Asked another way if I know my files are always going to be 'IA' should I just upload them that way or set the bucket that way from the offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) shows:

> **Lifecycle Transition Requests into Standard – Infrequent Access:**  $0.01 per 1,000 requests

It is better to upload directly into `STANDARD_IA`. This can be specified as part of the upload (eg see `--storage-class` option in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) `cp` command](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) ).

It is not possible to "set the bucket that way" -- the storage class is stored per-object.